# Select values for a column only if there are no rows with that value that satisfy a condition

Tags: sql, group-by, count, having

I have a table that stores logs of http fetches, let's say we have two columns: `fetch_url` and `success`. A few example rows:

```
success   fetch_url
TRUE      A
FALSE     A
FALSE     B
FALSE     B
FALSE     C
```

As you can see, there is at least one fetch for `A` that succeeded, but not a single fetch succeeded for `B` or for `C`. How can I write a query that will select only those fetch urls that have never succeeded? i.e.:

```
fetch_url
B
C
```

I'm trying to use some combination of `GROUP BY`, `COUNT`, and `HAVING`, but I can't get a correct query working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation:

```
select fetch_url
from t
group by fetch_url
having sum(case when sucess = 'TRUE' then 1 else 0 end) = 0;
```